# salesforce field service Is there a way to view your team's schedule from the mobile.(not just yours)

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice

We have been taking screenshots of gantt chart and sending it to our supervisors to check their team's schedule when on-job(they only have access to mobile device), is there a way to get the teams schedule present on the mobile app.